# Move last non-null value of each row - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe which is from a noSQL table, which implies the rows don't have the same length.
I need to retrieve the last non-null value of each row, move it to a new column 'h' and remove it from its initial position.

My initial DataFrame is:

```
      a           b     c     d   e     f     g
0  1635  01/01/2018  Null  Null  95   120    80
1  7364  01/15/2018   178   182  99  Null  Null
2  8947  01/20/2018  Null   190  92  Null  Null
3  6473  01/24/2018    45   122  99    32  Null
```

And I'd like to get this result:

```
      a           b     c     d     e     f     g   h
0  1635  01/01/2018  Null  Null    95   120  Null  80
1  7364  01/15/2018   178   182  Null  Null  Null  99
2  8947  01/20/2018  Null   190  Null  Null  Null  92
3  6473  01/24/2018    45   122    99  Null  Null  32
```

Answer (score 4):

Use, [`DataFrame.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) along with [`DataFrame.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) along `axis=1` to get the columns containing the last non null value, finally use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to get the values, corresponding to the `cols`:

```
cols = df.ne('Null').cumsum(axis=1).idxmax(axis=1)
df['h'] = df.lookup(df.index, cols)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
      a           b     c     d   e     f     g   h
0  1635  01/01/2018  Null  Null  95   120    80  80
1  7364  01/15/2018   178   182  99  Null  Null  99
2  8947  01/20/2018  Null   190  92  Null  Null  92
3  6473  01/24/2018    45   122  99    32  Null  32
```

Comment: great answer (+1), and congratulations for reaching 10000! :)

Comment: @DavideBrex Thanks, appreciate your comment.

Comment: Nice answer.+1 Congrats on 10K ;)

Answer (score 3):

As other solution you can use [last_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html). However, you first have to convert all the `Null` values to `np.NaN`.

```
df[df=="Null"] = np.NaN

df["h"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.last_valid_index()], axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
    a       b           c   d   e   f   g   h
0   1635    01/01/2018          95  120 80  80
1   7364    01/15/2018  178 182 99          99
2   8947    01/20/2018      190 92          92
3   6473    01/24/2018  45  122 99  32      32
```